# Authenticate a local Spring Boot service with Google Cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, init.d

I have a spring boot application that would run on a local server (not on a google cloud server). I plan to use a service account to allow the application to use Google Cloud Storage and Logging. I created a service account and an api key and downloaded the json file which looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "....",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": ".....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": ".....",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/....."
}
```

If I start the app in a development environment and set an environment variable that point to the json file, the app works as expected (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS).

However, I need to run the application as an init.d service in ubuntu (the application is configured to run as an executable jar).
I install my jar file as a service like this:

```
sudo ln -s /home/<user>/<jarname>.jar /etc/init.d/<service-name>
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/<service-name>
sudo update-rc.d <service-name> defaults
sudo service <service-name> start
```

The init.d service won't see the environment variable I set, so I need to authenticate in another way.

I installed `gcloud` and setup the service account like this:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account service-account-name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=credentials.json
gcloud config set project <projectId>
```

I also ran `gclout init` and it shows the service account I added.

When I run the application, I get a multiple errors: `com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: The request is missing a valid API key.`. Looks like something is missing, but I don't know what.

My `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/logging/logback-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <!-- Optional : filter logs at or above a level -->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <log>application.log</log> <!-- Optional : default java.log -->
        <!--resourceType>gae_app</resourceType--> <!-- Optional : default: auto-detected, fallback: global -->
        <loggingEventEnhancer>....LoggingEventEnhancer</loggingEventEnhancer>
        <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
    </appender>


    <root level="INFO">
        <!-- If running in GCP, remove the CONSOLE appender otherwise logs will be duplicated. -->
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD"/>

    </root>
</configuration>
```

Running `gcloud logging sinks list` works fine on the server, so the permissions should be right.

I know about `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/..`, but it doesn't work for me. (Also, this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/315#issuecomment-359077878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used systemd, it allows me to set any environment variable on service start.

1. place the executable jar and the application.properties in a folder, like `/opt/<name>` or `/home/<user>/<name>`
2. sudo nano `/etc/systemd/system/<name>.service`
3. Content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description text...etc
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Environment="LOGPATH=/var/<name>/logs"
Environment="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path-to-google-json/google/credentials.json"
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -pm 0755 ${LOGPATH}
ExecStart=/opt/<name>/<jar-name>.jar
PIDFile=/run/<name>/<name>%i.pid
Restart=on-abort
RuntimeDirectory=<name>
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
WorkingDirectory=/opt/<name>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Reload systemctl configs: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Set the service to start after system boot: `sudo systemctl enable <name>.service`
6. Start the service with `sudo systemctl start <name>.service`

Status: `sudo systemctl status <name>.service`

Follow the stdout: `sudo journalctl -u <name>.service --follow`